# Noun-mediated relationships not being found in OpenIE

Tags: stanford-nlp, information-extraction

I'm having difficulty extracting noun-mediated relationships as outlined in [Angeli et al](http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/2015angeli-openie.pdf).

When I run OpenIE locally with the input "US president Barack Obama traveled to India on Monday" only two relationships are extracted:

- (US president Barack Obama, traveled on, Monday)
- (US president Barack Obama, traveled to, India)
- **Not found but expected**: (Barack Obama, is president of, US)

However, when I run the same input at http://corenlp.run/, that third relationship looks to be extracted. Even more interestingly though, if I remove "Named Entities" as a possible annotator from corenlp.run, that third relationship is no longer found.

So I guess my question is what is the proper configuration (versions, models, annotators...) needed to properly extract noun-mediated relationships? On my local machine I downloaded v3.6.0, compiled the latest source code from the Master branch on GitHub, and then replaced stanford-corenlp-3.6.0.jar with the previously complied jar file. I then ran the following command from within the v3.6.0 folder:

```
java -mx1g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE -format ollie
```

Any help or insight would be a big help. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the current heuristics in the OpenIE system for extracting these relationships is to only extract them when named entity information is present (which we disable by default to improve speed), or else we drastically over-produce them. You can force-enable them with the flag `-triple.all_nominals`, but you've been warned :). The other easy option is to set the `-resolve_coref` flag, which will (1) run and resolve coreference when producing triples, but also (2) implicitly run the NER annotator. The last option is to specify the annotators directly to include NER:

```
java -mx1g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE -annotators "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse,ner,natlog,openie" -format ollie
```

Lastly, if you're using the 3.6.0 release, that's now fairly out of date. You're likely to get better results from the HEAD of the GitHub repo -- this is roughly what [corenlp.run](http://corenlp.run) tracks.

Comment: Awesome! I included the step to perform NER and am now extracting the "noun-mediated" relationships. Appreciate the help @GaborAngeli!